# All holo effects disappeared on redownloading sdk?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I was making an android app in eclipse, using some Holo elements in the UI. It worked fine. Then I deleted the eclipse and sdk folder, and redownloaded it. Didn't touch the app at all in the interim. Now all the holo effects are  gone, as you can see in the pictures below. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Here is my `styles.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">

        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/edittext_holo</item>
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <style name="edittext_holo" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#FF0000</item>
     </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

     </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: What is your target SDK version in your manifest? What does your application theme look like in XML?

Comment: @Tanis.7x Target SDK version: 21. This is the styles.xml: http://pastebin.com/zjRELk3G

Comment: thre is no SDK version 21

Comment: I'm impressed that you are targeting an Android version that doesn't currently exist and probably won't until next year. As for the styles- do you have another `styles.xml` under `values-v14`?

Comment: Yeah that's weird, don't know when I put it in there and why it didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `AppBaseTheme` style inherits from `android:Theme.Black`.

This is the pre-Holo default theme.

Your theme should inherit from a Holo theme (such as `android:Theme.Holo`). Based on your screenshot, you want `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`, so your `styles.xml` should look like this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

If you are supporting any SDK version below 14, this should go in the `values-14/styles.xml` file, as Holo does not exist on pre-14 devices.

For more information, see the [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) and the [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) documentation.